# Is there any math. function which gives sequence of numbers when ever i call it?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ui-automation

I have the following function:

```
function random()
{

    var whichProduct = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

    UIALogger.logMessage(whichProduct);
}
random();
```

This will give a random number in [1,4] whenever i call this function.

I want to know whether there is any other function which will give me a sequence of numbers in order (like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) when I call it.

Comment: this is a bad question, to be honest.

Comment: 8 questions with no accepted answers?

Answer (score 4):

Use closure, here is a simple example:  Each time you call `x()` it returns the next number in the `sequence(starting at 'startVal')`, but it does not compute every number in advance, only when it is called.

```
function seq(startVal) {  
   var i = startVal - 1;
   return function() {
      return i++;
   }
}
x = seq(1);
alert(x()); // alert(1)
alert(x()); // alert(2)
alert(x()); // alert(3)
```

Edit: Made a simple adjustment to pass in a starting value, sequence will begin there.

Comment: Not that it anyone 'wins' code golf, but couldn't you `return ++i;` and simplify the inner function slightly?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything built in to the language but you can define your own like so:

```js
var increasingSequence = function(a, b) {
  var seq=[], min=Math.min(a,b), max=Math.max(a,b), i;
  for (i=min; i<max; i++) {
    seq.push(i);
  }
  return seq;
};
increasingSequence(1, 5); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
increasingSequence(2, -2); // => [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Note also that [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a value in the range `[0,1)` (that is including zero but not including one), so if you want your random function to return `[1,5]` then you should implement it like so:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
```

Comment: I do not think this is what he is after.  I think he wants sequential numbers, not a series of random numbers.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: yeah, that makes sense, I interpreted his sequence as the special case of randomness that was increasing order but an actual increasing sequence is more likely =)  I've updated my answer.